# Adding S3 access to the SAM EFS example

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam

I'm using the sample SAM application that gives access to EFS.  Doing that puts the Lambda into a VPC, which cuts off my access to an S3 bucket that I need.  I've tried adding the following item to my template, but my Lambda still times out when I try to access the bucket:

```
  S3Endpoint:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint'
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: '*'
            Action:
              - 's3:*'
            Resource:
              - !GetAtt DataBucket.Arn
      ServiceName: !Sub 'com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.s3'
      VpcId: !Ref EfsLambdaVpc
```

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a networking problem where your VPC does not have access to the public internet.

Either this is not by design and you'll need to configure an internet gateway for your VPC & subnet where your lambda is running, or this is by design and you'll need to set up an S3 VPC endpoint.

For the first you can find some extra documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html), for setting up the VPC endpoint, you can have a look [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/managing-amazon-s3-access-with-vpc-endpoints-and-s3-access-points/).